# M2M relationships to self with attribute.

Tags: python, django, orm, m2m

I want to create cross selling product:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, default='')
    ...

class CrossSellingProduct(models.Model)
    parent_product = models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='cross_sellings')
    associate_product = models.ForeingKey(Product)
    double_sided = models.BooleanField(default=1)
```

I want to call function `cross_selling_products` on product instance and see all products which are associated. If `double_sided` is `True` I can see associated product in bouth way, if `False` only `parent` -> `associated_products`.

Is some smart way to implement this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to implement a ManyToMany-relation from the model *Product* to itsself? You can do that by

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, default='')
    cross_selling_products = models.ManyToManyField("self")
    ...
```

Then you can access the `cross_selling_products` on a `Product`'s instance.